# is it possible to increase the amount of RAM allowed per slot on a mother board?

Tags: hardware, memory

as the title says can the amount of ram a mother board accepts per slot be increase (maybe through a bios update) or is it a hard unchangeable limit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BIOS updates I have seen or for total memory, not per slot, but I would go look at updates for your bios and see anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the answer to this is No. Your memory controller is what limits the amount of Memory your board can accept and I am not aware of any BIOS update that can help with this.

Comment: it's theoretically possible that a BIOS bug has limited memory below what the controller chipset is capable of...

Answer (score 0):

I have always had the impression that this is hardware-limited as well but I'm not sure how true that is these days.  When a motherboard is designed the number of 'address lines' are set. At least in the olden days this mapped directly to the number of physical connections to the RAM.  Thus if for example a motherboard was designed with 30 address lines it could physically access 1GB (2^30) of RAM, as opposed to a motherboard with 32 address lines which could access 4GB (2^32) of RAM.

My sense however is that particular physical limitation has been largely removed by the many layers of abstraction which exist on modern motherboards.